# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that the input variable is type uniqueidentifier. When I execute this stored procedure, if I get the correct value that is in the table the stored procedure returns the record, but if I give the value wrong then the stored procedure should not return anything.

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Authorization_Token] 
    @Auth_Token uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        Customer_ID, Auth_Token, Token_Expiration 
    FROM
        Authorization_Token
    WHERE
        Auth_Token = @Auth_Token 
        AND GETDATE() < Token_Expiration 
 END
```

I am not sure why the freeze my post!!

I have tried the CAST like this:

```
CAST(Auth_Token as uniqueidentifier)
```

But I get same error.

Comment: You forgot to indicate what datatype the column `auth_token` is, which is key to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here, and say that the auth_token column in your table is a varchar (or nvarchar), and that one of the values in there is NOT a valid guid. Therefore, when you do your search, it's trying (and failing) to convert the values in that column to guids.

You could cast your incoming guid as a string in order for it to match the data type of the column, knowing of cousre, that it will never match those invalid strings.

Here's an illustration of what's going on

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#test') is not null drop table #test
create table #test
(
    AuthToken char(36)
)

insert into #Test
select cast(newid() as varchar(36)) union all --this is fine
select 'Not a guid' --this is not

declare @authtoken uniqueidentifier = newid()

select *
from #test
where AuthToken = @authtoken
```

To solve the issue, you can either refactor the select statement to cast @authtoken as a string like this:

```
select *
from #test
where AuthToken = cast(@authtoken as char(36))
```

If you have SQL Server 2012 you could also use try_convert on the column

```
select *
from #test
where try_convert(uniqueidentifier, AuthToken) = @authtoken
```

EDIT: Here's a little bit of code I wrote to test if a string is a GUID. I probalby wouldnt use this in a production system, but it may help you root out the invalid strings.

```
declare @testGUID char(36) = newid(),
@guidPattern varchar(1000) =
    replicate('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 8) 
    + '-' 
    + replicate('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 4) 
    + '-' 
    + replicate('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 4) 
    + '-'
    + replicate('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 4) 
    + '-'
    + replicate('[0-9A-Fa-f]', 12)


if @testGUID like @guidPattern
    select 'ITS A GUID!'
else
    select 'OH NOES'
```